# Issues with connecting to grpc service running in Go with python

Tags: python, grpc

I am having issues in connecting to the grpc service running in GO using the python library

I am using  the library

```
grpcio==1.10.1
```

Here is my code

```
import grpc
from hello_world import hello_world_pb2_grpc
from hello_world import hello_world_pb2
channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:5000')
stub =hello_world_pb2_grpc.CallStub(channel)
stub.Call()
```

I am getting the following error after setting the debug mode on when I do

```
channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:5000')


>>> E0614 21:11:00.273830440   14198 channel_connectivity.cc:126] watch_completion_error: "Cancelled"
E0614 21:11:00.273870160   14198 completion_queue.cc:634]    Operation failed: tag=0x7fbaab82b320, error={"created":"@1529010660.273816994","description":"Timed out waiting for connection state change","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/channel_connectivity.cc","file_line":133}
E0614 21:11:00.474877364   14195 channel_connectivity.cc:126] watch_completion_error: "Cancelled"
E0614 21:11:00.474967852   14195 completion_queue.cc:634]    Operation failed: tag=0x7fbaab82b358, error={"created":"@1529010660.474849365","description":"Timed out waiting for connection state change","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/channel_connectivity.cc","file_line":133}
E0614 21:11:00.675819616   14198 channel_connectivity.cc:126] watch_completion_error: "Cancelled"
E0614 21:11:00.675860536   14198 completion_queue.cc:634]    Operation failed: tag=0x7fbaab82b358, error={"created":"@1529010660.675806653","description":"Timed out waiting for connection state change","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/channel_connectivity.cc","file_line":133}

E0614 21:11:00.876819325   14195 channel_connectivity.cc:126] watch_completion_error: "Cancelled"
E0614 21:11:00.876855700   14195 completion_queue.cc:634]    Operation failed: tag=0x7fbaab82b320, error={"created":"@1529010660.876806994","description":"Timed out waiting for connection state change","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/channel_connectivity.cc","file_line":133}
```

This is what the error looks like

```
E0614 19:43:39.385612320    8409 lockfree_event.cc:209]      LockfreeEvent::SetReady: 0x7f7b18001a28 curr=0x7f7b14001120
E0614 19:43:39.385634661    8409 lockfree_event.cc:209]      LockfreeEvent::SetReady: 0x7f7b18001a30 curr=0x2
E0614 19:43:39.385664271    8409 lockfree_event.cc:94]       LockfreeEvent::NotifyOn: 0x7f7b18001a28 curr=(nil) closure=0x7f7b14001120
E0614 19:43:39.390243947    8409 lockfree_event.cc:209]      LockfreeEvent::SetReady: 0x7f7b18001a28 curr=0x7f7b14001120
E0614 19:43:39.390261213    8409 lockfree_event.cc:209]      LockfreeEvent::SetReady: 0x7f7b18001a30 curr=0x2
E0614 19:43:39.390363730    8409 lockfree_event.cc:160]      LockfreeEvent::SetShutdown: 0x7f7b18001a28 curr=(nil) err={"created":"@1529005419.390300526","description":"Delayed close due to in-progress write","file":"src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":589,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1529005419.390289956","description":"Endpoint read failed","file":"src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":2446,"occurred_during_write":0,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1529005419.390275545","description":"Socket closed","fd":7,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc","file_line":423,"grpc_status":14,"target_address":"ipv4:127.0.0.1:8081"}]}]}
E0614 19:43:39.390380912    8409 lockfree_event.cc:160]      LockfreeEvent::SetShutdown: 0x7f7b18001a30 curr=0x2 err={"created":"@1529005419.390300526","description":"Delayed close due to in-progress write","file":"src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":589,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1529005419.390289956","description":"Endpoint read failed","file":"src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":2446,"occurred_during_write":0,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1529005419.390275545","description":"Socket closed","fd":7,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc","file_line":423,"grpc_status":14,"target_address":"ipv4:127.0.0.1:8081"}]}]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/me/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 500, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/home/me/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 434, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, Socket closed)>
```

It is showing it is not able to connect to the given service at the given port. However, other services are able to connect to the given port, written in other languages.

Also if I do telnet `localhost:5000`, it is able to connect

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: Do you have a proxy configured? If so, see if unsetting http_proxy and https_proxy have an effect: unset http_proxy; unset https_proxy; python hello_world.py.

Comment: @msmolens. I don't have the proxy set

Comment: @rajansthapit Have you tried upgrading to the latest `grpcio` package?